# How to return custom datatype from c++ DLL method to C# code?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Hello i would like to put some logic of my programme written in C# into C++ DLL file. I have never used such a solution before and i have a question. Let's assume i have a simple code snippet like below:

```
//header file:

...
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int fib(int num);
...

//cpp file:

...
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int fib(int num)
{

    if (num == 1 || num == 0)
        return num;
    else
        return fib(num - 2) + fib(num - 1);

}
...

//and example C# code:

...

[DllImport("fib.dll", EntryPoint="fib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int CppFib(int a);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      ...
      Console.WriteLine(CppFib(25));
      ...

}
```

The code just has to simulate some calculation which needs to be executed in a dll. Everything compiles and works properly, but what if i had to return not a simple value type like an integer number, but some custom data. As an example:

```
//cpp:
...

struct Point
{

    double x;
    double y;

};

...

//csharp:
...

IEnumerable<Point> points = GetPoints();

...
```

Here's the Point struct defined in C++ library. I need to implement a method which returns a collection of Points. A list or a table, doesn't matter i just would like to have a possibility to iterate through them. I guess C# code somehow must know how the type looks like, maybe it needs some kind of declaration?? How the conversion looks between C++ collections and C# collections? Best regards.

Comment: c++ doesn't know what IEnumerable is.  s

Comment: c++ doesn't know what IEnumerable is.  So use Point[] points = GetPoints();  But I believe this will still fail because c++ is returning unmanaged memory.   What you are returning back is an array of pointers which is 4 bytes * Length of Array where the 4 bytes are pointers to the actual Point structure.  A double is 8 bytes so Point is 16 bytes.  The data that is returned is on the execution stack and after returning from the method the stack is dispose so you cannot retrieve the data.  Best way of returning is a an IntPtr as the parameter : Getpoints(IntPtr data).

Comment: You have to allocate the data before calling and in c++ must put data consecutively in memory and not as a **Point.  You would want *Point[] where the array is consecutive in memory.  A **Point is an array of pointers where the actual data can be any place in memory and not necessary in consecutive memory locations.